# Redirect to Maintenance Fails on Specific URI - scwebadminapp/index.html

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, aix

All the potential URIs I've entered go to the Maintenance page except when using the specific scwebadminapp URI here https://servername.domain.com/scwebadminapp/index.html

The rules I'm using are:

```
   RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/erp_maintenance.html -f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/erp_maintenance.html
   RewriteRule ^.*$ /erp_maintenance.html [L]
```

I'm trying to understand to write a second RewriteCond & RewriteRule that handles 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} scwebadminapp ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REQUEST_FILENAME needs a full filesystem path, you may want to use REQUEST_URI instead or...

Try this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/erp_maintenance.html -f
RewriteRule ^(?!erp_maintenance.html).* /erp_maintenance.html [L]
```

**Explanation:** (?!...) is used as a "negative lookahead", made to avoid loops and situations like this where the destination is excluded from a catch-almost-all regex match.